# error that the header can not be reset

Tags: node.js

I have a main file called server.js in which it has a method in post to call the request of url

```
var goToOther = require('./goToOther.js');

app.post ('/goToOther/', function (req, res) {
var data = {
    "Error": 1,
    "Zone" ""
};
    sms.goToOther (req, res, msgsms;

});
```

I have another file that is called the goToOther goToOther.js

```
exports.goToOtherUrl = function (req, res, next, msgsms) {
    var data = {
        "Error": 1,
        "Sms": ""
    };

var url = "http://www.google.com.br";


req.redirect ({
    uri: url,
    method: "POST"
}, Function (error, response, body) {
    console.log (error);
    //console.log(body);
    date ["error"] = 0;
    date ["sms"] = "successfully sent";
    res.json (data);
    next ();

});

};
```

I read some texts about it and did not understand what is happening and remade several times what I read between them I tried to recreate a new post method that sends calls the url but continued giving the error that the header can not be reset. The error is basically this: Error: Can not set after headers They are sent.

```
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader 
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: remove `next ();` after `res.json (data);` line.

Comment: I did this  and I test and the same error  i used this site to test:
http://hurl.it/

Comment: The code execute and closes the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send a response (`res.json(...);`) after sending a redirect (`req.redirect(...);`). This will cause the server to try to set headers when they were already sent.